# Fastest way too check input for punctuations in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Just as the title says whats the fastest way to check if a userinput contains a punctuations except / , i'm New to VBA and struggeling with this for A couple of hours now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if the string contains anything thats not A to Z, 0 to 9 or /

```
hasPunctuation = astring like "*[!A-Za-z0-9/]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is letters, numerals, and the slash then is one way:

```
Sub PuncCheck()
    Dim strng1 As String, strng2 As String

    strng1 = "qwerty12345678~!@#$%^&*()_+"
    strng2 = "qwerty12345678/"
    Call StringCheck(strng1)
    Call StringCheck(strng2)
End Sub


Sub StringCheck(sIN As String)
    Dim i As Long, sCH As String

    For i = 1 To Len(sIN)
        sCH = Mid(sIN, i, 1)
        If sCH Like "[0-9a-zA-Z]" Or sCH = "/" Then
        Else
            MsgBox "string has junk"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "string has no junk"
End Sub
```